# helm-projectile-ag : How can I refine the grep results further?

Tags: helm, projectile

I have a newb question regarding the use of [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) in the context of [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile).

I'm using `helm-projectile-ag` to grep for strings in a large code base. The performance is excellent, but I'm needing to refine search results further.

Typically, I'd get something along these lines, where I'm interested in the `Core` bits, but want to ignore hits in unrelated files:

```
Unrelated1/some_file.cpp: void getHash();
Core/include/hash.h: void getHash()
Core/src/bla.cpp: return getHash();
Core/src/again.cpp: a = getHash(b) + getHash(c);
Unrelated2/some_file.cpp: void getHash();
```

What I would like to do is to refine the results further by file path, so only strings under `Core` are shown. Is there a way to pass the buffer from `helm-projectile-ag` to another Helm refining buffer somehow, or to refine the results in the buffer `helm-projectile-ag` uses?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. you should consider a feature request to helm-ag maintainer.

Comment: Finally remembered to log this request. Here's a link: [Feature request: Enable space characters to interactively narrow selection #108](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag/issues/108)

Comment: The requested feature was implemented recently for `M-x helm-ag` (which works a treat), but it's not yet available in `M-x helm-projectile-ag`. Hopefully it'll be supported in Projectile soon :)